# No components in

Tags: reactjs

I started learning react. Started a React app with my commant prompt, everything is downloaded correctly, but the app that was started does not contain components. Every tutorial I try their apps start with this line in `App.js` file `import React, {Component} from 'react';` but I don't have that.
Components are actually started with 'class App extends Component', but I dont have that. There is also no render method in this component.

I do not know what to try.

```
 function App () {
  return (...)
 }
```

Comment: Can you show more code ?  Besides, if you have `function App () { return (...) }

`, it is already a component (this one is called functional) and you can do then a classic `ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.body)`

Comment: Please follow reactjs official documentation or https://medium.com/@thechrisbull/4-different-kinds-of-components-creating-a-react-ui-component-framework-saga-a-designer-9043c0cc597 for your better understanding.... because what you can see now in App.js . it's functional component.

Comment: Here is more code. I understand that this is a functional component.
This code will work in my app, but if I try to write anything else for example after/before Header component it will not be recognized.
function App () {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      </div>
  );
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this path if you copied your project from another external source  :

1. Create a folder
2. Go to cmd of the current folder
3. In your cmd write:

   create-react-app myapp
4. When the download  finished, 
   In cmd write `code .`(this opens visual studio code and opens your react files)

Or simply open your editor and open folder in it

5. In cmd (terminal) of your project folder write `npm start`, and your app will load on localhost:3000
6. **finally answer of your question You can edit your project, by going to src folder and editing app.js**

**update**
*** I checked `create react app` myself it seems In the new version of create-react-app
It doesn't create class-based component anymore (it creates a function based component) and you need to change it to class-based component manually if you want to.***

Update2, to change function based to class ,delete app.js codes and replace these:

```
Import React , { Component } from "react"
class App extends Component {
Render() {
    return <div> test </div>;
 }}
 export default App;
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: I did all, except that I use Atom.

Comment: That is exactly what I thaght it was. But if I try to create class-based component in the project everything will fall apart. Adding render method manually does not work either.

Comment: Can I continue with this udemy course if I use functional component and he is using class-based components?

Comment: @SlavenBunijevac yeah sure, just copy their code and you will be fine.good luck mate